# Adding a specific error message to a view in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

Is it possible to add a specific error message to a field in a view?
Currently I have validation on the model to check whether a field is empty (ValidationMessageFor<>) and I am using validation summary for specific errors.
What I'm wondering is whether the specific error message created for the summary can replace the ValidationMessageFor<>?

Model:

```
 [Required]
 public string SchoolCode { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SchoolCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "School Code" } })

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SchoolCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Controller:

```
var schoolExists = RepositoryHelper.GetSchoolByCode(model.SchoolCode);
if (schoolExists == null)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, @"No school exists with this code");
    return View(model);
}
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    //do other stuff
}
```

So if the model state isn't valid it returns the model error, but if an incorrect code is entered it adds "No school exists with this code" to the validation summary. Could I replace the school code model error with the school code summary error?

Comment: In future please format your code for better reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the property name in the `AddModelError()` method

```
ModelState.AddModelError("SchoolCode", "No school exists with this code");
```

so that it will be displayed in the placeholder identified by `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SchoolCode, ... })`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to override the error messages. All that you need to do is to reference the item in the `ModelState.AddModelError` method call and to specify the error message text.

You can override the following error messages:

- The default error message if no error message is specified
- The error message that you specified

The generated `HTML` output for your textbox will look something like this:

```
<input
    class="input-validation-error form-control text-box single-line"
    data-val="true"
    data-val-required="Source code is required"
    id="SchoolCode"
    name="SchoolCode"
    placeholder="School Code"
    type="text"
    value="" />
```

It is important to note the values of the `id` and `name` propeties. They have been set to `SchoolCode`. When you need to override the error message you need to make use of the value `SchoolCode` so that you know which HTML element you are referencing/working with.

So adding a custom error message based on some other criteria you need to change your code to look like the following:

```
if (schoolExists == null)
{
     ModelState.AddModelError("SchoolCode", "No school exists with this code");

     return View(model);
}
```

I hope this helps.